# persist Integrity constraint oneToOne

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Entities :

Entity Miejsce

```
class Miejsce
{

  /**
 *
 * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="miejsce_id")
 */
protected $lokalizacja;
```

Entity Lokalizacja

```
class Lokalizacja {

    /**
     * Lokalizacja.id = Miejsce.id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;


       /**
 * @var Miejsce
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce", inversedBy="lokalizacja")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="miejsce_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $miejsce;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $miejsce_id;
```

i Create new Miejsce

```
$miejsce = new Miejsce();
```

....
    $em->persist($miejsce);
    $em->flush();

and get

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`symfony2_KPB_lazy`.`mMiejsce`, CONSTRAINT `FK_41DB4C8BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `mLokalizacja` (`miejsce_id`))
```

if i first setup lokalizacja

```
 $lokalizacja = new Lokalizacja();
        $lokalizacja->setLat($a['lat']);
        $lokalizacja->setLng($a['lng']);
        $em->persist($lokalizacja);
        $em->flush();
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'miejsce_id' cannot be null

if i add persist

```
 /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="miejsce_id")
     */
    protected $lokalizacja;
```

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO mLokalizacja (miejsce_id, lat, lng, zoom, textAdres, mMiejscowosci_id, mPowiaty_id, mWojewodztwa_id, street) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, 49.658192, 18.825332, null, null, null, null, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'miejsce_id' cannot be null

when run code

```
    $miejsce = new Miejsce();

        $lokalizacja = new Lokalizacja();
        $lokalizacja->setLat($a['lat']);
        $lokalizacja->setLng($a['lng']);
        $lokalizacja->setMiejsce($miejsce);

        $miejsce->setLokalizacja($lokalizacja);

 $em->persist($miejsce);
        $em->flush();
```

when i try add miejsce in phpMyAdmin - i get

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`symfony2_KPB`.`mMiejsce`, CONSTRAINT `FK_41DB4C8BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `mLokalizacja` (`miejsce_id`))

So how to add Miejsce ?

UPDATE1

```
class Miejsce
{

    /**
     * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja")
     */
    protected $lokalizacja;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mLokalizacja", indexes={
    @ORM\Index(name="index_latLng", columns={"lat","lng"})
})
*
 */
class Lokalizacja {

    /**
     * @var Miejsce
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce", inversedBy="lokalizacja")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="miejsce_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $miejsce;
```

i update database and see  (this is phpmyadmin table structure):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mMiejsce` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazwa` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lokalizacja_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

and lokalizacja 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mLokalizacja` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` double NOT NULL,
  `lng` double NOT NULL,
  `zoom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `miejsce_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_4FC27791464204DC` (`miejsce_id`),
```

Why doctrine add lokalizacja_id to mMiejsce ? 
And still save is not possible

UPDATE2
i add mappedBy="miejsce", database look ok now but when i try save

```
class Miejsce
{
    /**
     * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja" , mappedBy="miejsce")
     */
    protected $lokalizacja;
```

have error :

A new entity was found through the relationship 'Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce#lokalizacja' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja@000000006200f93900007f919f6a5a6f. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja#__toString()' to get a clue.

so i add ,cascade={"persist"}

```
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja" , mappedBy="miejsce" ,cascade={"persist"})
```

now entity save succes but :) 
i cant delete it - when i try delete miejsce -

i found  onDelete="CASCADE" - but have error :

```
Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\OneToOne declared on property Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce::$lokalizacja does not have a property named "onDelete". Available properties: targetEntity, mapped  
  By, inversedBy, cascade, fetch, orphanRemoval
```

when add to * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja" , mappedBy="miejsce" ,cascade={"persist"})

So where add cascade delete ?

UPDATE3

ok when i add

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="miejsce_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

to lokalizacja everythink work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to establish a oneToOne bidirectional relationship. Such a relationship (as all bidirectional ones) needs the mention `inversedBy` on one side and `mappedBy` on the other, which you forgot in your annotation.

For more detailed informations about relationships, see [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional).

But regarding your particular need, you can start with the following.

**Miejsce:**

```
class Miejsce
{
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Lokalizacja", mappedBy="miejsce", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $lokalizacja;
```

Here is where you forgot `mappedBy`.

**Lokalizacja:**

```
class Lokalizacja
{
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce", inversedBy="lokalizacja")
     */
    private $miejsce;
```

When you join based on the `id`, JoinColumn is optional and you can omit it (as I did).

**Then, you go on normally with:**

```
// (...)
$em->persist($miejsce);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Yes saving work but canot delete - how to setup - if i remove miejsce i want remove lokalizacja